# android - ListAdapter deleting item - refreshing view

Tags: android, listview, cursor, listadapter

I'm trying to delete items from a ListView using a custom adapter which extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

When I try to delete one of the list items, I want to the `ListView` to refresh itself. I have read from other posts, that you can do this by calling `Cursor.requery().`

While the database is consistent, that is, the deletion takes place, `Cursor.requery()` returns true, but instead of showing me the updated list, it shows me an empty list with the empty TextView I have set in my xml file with this id `android:id="@id/android:empty"`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found my own problem.

I was closing the database.

Perhaps I only need to close the database when the activity is paused/stopped etc..

Comment: You cannot close the database while the `Cursor` is still in use.

Answer (score 2):

You have other code in there beyond the `requery()` call that is messing things up. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants) demonstrating the use of `requery()` to update a `ListView` when a new item is inserted or deleted.

Comment: My adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter and only overrides newView and bindView. Is there a method that I need to override, that because I'm not, might be causing the trigger to the empty list view?

Comment: @kkudi: No. I doubt your problem is in the adapter. Something else is getting rid of the adapter, perhaps.